# CSS: slide a div out to the right only to width of the parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm having some CSS issues I hope someone here can help with. I basically am trying to set a group of inline divs that slide out to the right, expanding to the width of the parent div containing them. As you can see from the jsfiddle I have (https://jsfiddle.net/0o9bw101/), the divs expand to the width of the parent div, instead of expanding only to the rightmost border of the parent div. If anyone can help I'd be quite thankful. Thank you in advance!

Here is the CSS I'm using in case you want to see it here:

```
.container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

.greyDiv {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: black;
}

.greyDiv:hover {
  transition: 2s;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute
}
```

Comment: you need javascript/jQuery for this - the different widths have to be calculated based on the position of the DIVs inside the parent. Or you use separate settings for each element, then it's possible in CSS alone.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```css
 .container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.greyDiv {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.greyDiv:hover {
  transition: 2s;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='greyDiv'></div>
  <div class='greyDiv'></div>
  <div class='greyDiv'></div>
  <div class='greyDiv'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Kind of. I'm trying to make it so that it slides out with the right amount of right padding too, not just slide it out and hide any overflow (meaning it shouldn't really do anything if you hover over the last div on the right). Also, in that posted code the last div disappears when I hover over any of the other ones for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

The trick is to add another box inside main container.

**DEMO**: https://jsfiddle.net/0o9bw101/3/

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='invisible_container'>  
    <div class='greyDiv'></div>
    <div class='greyDiv'></div>
    <div class='greyDiv'></div>
    <div class='greyDiv'></div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

*previous answer*:

It's hard to do when you mix parent's with in % with children margins in px.
Also having parent's position set to something other than default helps a bit.

Here is working example for you:

```
.container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}

.greyDiv {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-left: 2%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.greyDiv:hover {
  transition: 2s;
  width: 96%;
  position: absolute
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/0o9bw101/2/

Comment: ahh, my solution works only for first square, gotta fix that :)

Comment: completed my answer with another, this time fully working, solution

Answer (score 0):

This might not be quite what you were going for, but here elements will grow to the full width of the container (left to right) regardless of it's starting position using 2 extra elements per object.

The `.inner` is used to grow the background to the full width

The `.placeholder` is used to keep the other elements from collapsing left

```css
@keyframes grow {
    from {width: 0%;}
    to {width: 92%;}
}

.container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
}

.greyDiv {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 4%;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.inner {
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.placeholder {
    display: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    margin: 20px 4%;
}

.greyDiv:hover {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 4;
}

.greyDiv:hover + .placeholder {
  display: inline-block;
}

.greyDiv:hover .inner {
  display: inline-block;
  left: 4%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  animation-name: grow;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='greyDiv'>1a<div class="inner">1x</div></div><div class="placeholder"></div>
  <div class='greyDiv'>2a<div class="inner">2x</div></div><div class="placeholder"></div>
  <div class='greyDiv'>3a<div class="inner">3x</div></div><div class="placeholder"></div>
  <div class='greyDiv'>4a<div class="inner">4x</div></div><div class="placeholder"></div>
</div>
```